# Update label text in background worker winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am using BackGroundWorker class to insert some values in sqlserver. I have for loop here to insert values. i am using following code

```
 public void bw_Convert_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {           
        e.Result = e.Argument;
        for (int i = 0; i <  fTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_CDR_ANALYZER (LNG_UPLOAD_ID, DAT_START, LNG_DURATION, INT_DIRECTION, INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE, \n" +
                    "TXT_TARGET_NUMBER, TXT_OTHER_PARTY_NUMBER, TXT_TARGET_IMSI, TXT_TARGET_IMEI, TXT_TARGET_CELL_ID, TXT_ROAMING_NETWORK_COMPANY_NAME) VALUES \n" +
                    "(@UPLOAD_ID, @START_DATE, @DURATION, @DIRECTION, @CALL_TYPE, @TARGET_NUMBER, @OTHER_PARTY_NUMBER, @IMSI, @IMEI, @CELL_ID, @ROAMING_NAME)", sqlCon);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UPLOAD_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@START_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["CallDate"];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DURATION", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["CallDuration"];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DIRECTION", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GetCallDirection(fTable.Rows[i]["CallDirection"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CALL_TYPE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GetCallType(fTable.Rows[i]["CallType"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TARGET_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["TargetNo"];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@OTHER_PARTY_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["OtherPartyNo"];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMSI", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["IMSI"];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["IMEI"];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CELL_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["CellID"];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ROAMING_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["RoamingCompany"];
                sqlCon.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
            bw_Convert.ReportProgress((100 * i) / fTable.Rows.Count);  
            **Label1.Text = i.ToString() + "Files Converted";** // getting error Here.                  
        }    
    }
```

How can i update the Label1 text here

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should work to change the GUI from a background thread.

```
Label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
   Label1.Text = i.ToString() + "Files Converted";});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't access UI interface objects like a label inside a DoWork method.
The DoWork is running on a different thread than the UI elements.
You need to update your interface through the ProgressChanged event or calling a delegate.

First set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property  of the BackgroundWorker to True,
then, the call to `ReportProgress` method, will raise the event `ProgressChanged` that will be run in the same thread of your interface elements

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     Label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement the ProgressChanged-Event.

```
private void bw_Convert_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //The progress in percentage
   int progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
   //A custom-value you can pass by calling ReportProgress in DoWork
   object obj = e.UserState;
}
```

Comment: And you can use UserState to pass through custom messages from your executing code

Answer (score 2):

//You can also try this update your label

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
          {
             Label1.Text = i.ToString() + "Files Converted";
          }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I was already within the Progress Changed Background Worker Event but even using both versions of the Method Invoker above did not help. Then I tried this and it worked:

```
 lblCount.Text = string.Format("Total Directories: {0} Total Files: {1}", TotalDirectories, TotalFiles);
 lblCount.Update();
```