# Changing label text in background worker Error

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am trying to change a label on the form during a background worker process However it says unhandled exception. I've looked at the error and it said to invoke it like the accepted answer says here: [Update label text in background worker winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759688/update-label-text-in-background-worker-winforms)

I have done this successfully with changing values inside a checkbox list, but I've used the same method and for the label it won't invoke, I get the red error line in the code when I type it.

My Background Worker:

```
private void bw2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    func.sshConnect();
    for (int num = 0; num < checklist.Items.Count; num++)
    {
        if (checklist.GetItemChecked(num))
        {
            string project = checklist.Items[num].ToString();
            lblStatus.Text = "Opening " + project + "..."; //error here
            if (func.svnCheckoutProject(project))
            {
                lblStatus.Text = project + " Opened"; //same error here
                func.sshRunCommand("echo " + project + " >> " + Properties.Settings.Default.serverUserFilesPath + Properties.Settings.Default.Username);
            }
            else
            {
                //error message
            }
        }
        worker.ReportProgress(num * (100 / checklist.Items.Count));
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing the lines with errors with this, but in visual studio it gives it a red line under invoke and won't let me build it.

```
lblStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lblStatus.Text = "Opening " + project + "..."; });
```

Visual studio points me to here when the error appears: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHInvalidOperation.WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)
I used this method for the checkbox list and it worked but try it for the label and it doesn't work.

Any ideas of why it isn't working or another way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't update your UI controls from the `DoWork` event - you're on a separate thread from the UI thread. You can call Invoke, but it's really not the right place for it.

The `BackgroundWorker` already provides a construct for periodically updating the UI thread while the worker is running, and you're already using it - it's the `ReportProgress` method. That's the place you should be updating your Label from. Anything in there runs back on the main UI thread.

---

You can pass any `object` you want to the `ReportProgess` method:

```
worker.ReportProgress(num * (100 / checklist.Items.Count),
                      string.Format("Opening {0} ...", project));
```

Then cast the value back and use it in the `ProgressChanged` event:

```
void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var message = e.UserState.ToString();

    lblStatus.Text = message;
}
```

Comment: I know im on a seperate thread, thats the point of the code so it doesnt freeze my form. report progress takes an int as a variable, how exactly would I send a string to it? The background worker affects what string is shown so it would have to be called from there, the thread safe way of calling it worked for the checkboxlist but not for the label, so it can be done

Comment: Excellent, not exactly what I was looking for but it works better. The only problem I see is having to report the percentage when its not required but thats a small preference. Thanks, it worked well

Comment: Ive moved on to another level in my code. My backgroundworker handles logon so my form doesnt freeze, the problem is that I now want to update a control during the background process (ive already using the percentage uservar for the status label). would it be best to create an object array and pass the required info through the reportprogress or create 2 backgrund workers which work one after another?

Comment: I knew i could pass whatever i wanted through but it was how to do it as i was already sending something through. I like the look of Tuples and ill look into using them. Thanks again

Comment: Looking t it how would I cast it back into a tuple after its been passed into report progress? I cant seem to get it to cast to get the values out

Comment: ok ill create a new post in a bit, I have done what you just posted but it came up with an exception. Ill post a new question on it

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, you would want to use BeginIvoke rather than Invoke

```
    public void changeLabelText(System.Windows.Forms.Label lib, String whateva)
    {
        if (lib.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lib.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => changeLabelText(lib, whateva)));
        }
        else
        {
            lib.Text = whateva;
        }
    }
```

and the call the method in your DoWork

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
//do something
//change the text of a label lb1
changeLabelText(lb1, "I'm reporting some progress....");
}
```

Comment: When using a BackgroundWorker, you should avoid Invoke or BeginInvoke for UI controls.  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) : You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.

Comment: There are plenty of times when ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted are not sufficient at all. yes, you should be careful as you could get unexpected results when updating a control from several threads or get a deadlock, however I could easily interpret "should be careful" as do it, but with caution rather than "you shouldn't be doing it at all." Again, there might be dangers that I am not aware of. On a different note, we all should probably be using Tasks rather than Background Workers