# C# Backgroundworker download progress in label, get bytes in label

Tags: c#

I've created an application that patches my game servers files.
However, I've got 3 problems which I can't solve:

1. When downloading a new patch, it doesn't update the progressbar instantly, but refreshes it after around 30-40 seconds
2. I want a label to show how much mega bytes they are downloading, and how much they have so far (for example: 122Mb/750Mb
3. When downloading, I want a label to show ~% of how much it has downloaded so far

I am not sure how to add number 2 and 3, and the number 1 problem just seems ridiculous, because there's nothing that indicates it should refresh after 30-40 seconds in my coding (at least as far as I know)

My backgroundWorker1_DoWork:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Defines the server's update directory
        string Server = "http://localhost/dl/game-updates/";

        //Defines application root
        string Root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        //Make sure version file exists
        FileStream fs = null;
        if (!File.Exists("version"))
        {
            using (fs = File.Create("version"))
            {

            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("version"))
            {
                sw.Write("1.0");
            }
        }
        //checks client version
        string lclVersion;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("version"))
        {
            lclVersion = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        decimal localVersion = decimal.Parse(lclVersion);

        //server's list of updates
        XDocument serverXml = XDocument.Load(@Server + "Updates.xml");

        //The Update Process
        foreach (XElement update in serverXml.Descendants("update"))
        {
            string version = update.Element("version").Value;
            string file = update.Element("file").Value;

            decimal serverVersion = decimal.Parse(version);


            string sUrlToReadFileFrom = Server + file;

            string sFilePathToWriteFileTo = Root + file;

            if (serverVersion > localVersion)
            {
                Uri url = new Uri(sUrlToReadFileFrom);
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
                System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();

                Int64 iSize = response.ContentLength;

                Int64 iRunningByteTotal = 0;

                using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    using (System.IO.Stream streamRemote = client.OpenRead(new Uri(sUrlToReadFileFrom)))
                    {
                        using (Stream streamLocal = new FileStream(sFilePathToWriteFileTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                        {
                            int iByteSize = 0;
                            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[iSize];
                            while ((iByteSize = streamRemote.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                streamLocal.Write(byteBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
                                iRunningByteTotal += iByteSize;

                                double dIndex = (double)(iRunningByteTotal);
                                double dTotal = (double)byteBuffer.Length;
                                double dProgressPercentage = (dIndex / dTotal);
                                int iProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage * 100);

                                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);
                            }

                            streamLocal.Close();
                        }

                        streamRemote.Close();
                    }
                }

                //unzip
                using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
                {
                    foreach (ZipEntry zipFiles in zip)
                    {
                        zipFiles.Extract(Root + "\\", true);
                    }
                }

                //download new version file
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile(Server + "version.txt", @Root + "version");

                //Delete Zip File
                deleteFile(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

My backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label1.Text = "Downloading updates...";
    }
```

And my backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        settings_btn.Enabled = true;
        start_btn_disabled.Enabled = false;
        start_btn_disabled.Visible = false;
        start_btn.Visible = true;
        start_btn.Enabled = true;
        progressBar1.Value = 100;
        label1.Text = "Client is up to date!";
    }
```

Also, a side note: I'm also having a bit problems of updating labels in backgroundWorker2_DoWork?
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update label text in background worker winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759688/update-label-text-in-background-worker-winforms)

Comment: Welcome on this site John. If you want better chance to get answered, have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @demonplus that person on that post is using backgroundworker to insert mysql values.
I'm not. You should read the post before saying it's a duplicate

Comment: @JohnK when someone suggest a duplicate it may mean that there is code in that question that can be of use to you - I think you took it the wrong way. Your question is partially about updating labels when using `BackgroundWorker` which is the same as the linked question.

Comment: Oh. My bad. I'm sorry, @demonplus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some working code which updates a label on Form1 using the BackgroundWorker.

Create a new Windows Form project and drop it in your code and it'll work. 
It's super ugly, but it works. 
After that, just plug your code into the DoWork method and calculate your value and send to ReportProgress.

Keep in mind that the work done in DoWork method is the actual Background Thread.
That means that in that method (DoWork) you cannot access UI (form) elements because they are on the UI thread.

[image]

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

        void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }

        void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            FakeCountingWork();
        }


        private void FakeCountingWork()
        {
            int totalNumber = 100;
            int progressCounter = 0;
            while (progressCounter < totalNumber)
            {
                int fakecounter = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
                {
                    fakecounter++;
                }
                progressCounter++;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progressCounter);
            }
        }
    }
```

##################################  EDITED TO ADD OTHER FUNCTIONALITY

Okay, here's how you can implement a label which displays the number of bytes downloaded so far.
Add a second label named label2 to your form.
Next alter the following methods from my previous example.
Here we are going to use the UserState to pass an extra value to the ProgressChanged Event.  It's very simple.  You can see that I'm generating a random number and it will now appear in Label2. This is where you could show your number of bytes.

```
  void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
            label2.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        }

 private void FakeCountingWork()
        {
            int totalNumber = 100;
            int progressCounter = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (progressCounter < totalNumber)
            {
                int fakecounter = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < 100000000; x++)
                {
                    fakecounter++;
                }
                progressCounter++;
               updateValue = rnd.Next();
              backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progressCounter,updateValue);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm (for the showing percentage part) thank you!

Comment: @JohnK I added the additional functionality implementing the UserState object and passing an additional value into the ProgressChanged event to show you how you could show number of bytes with another label.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would make this work with my int64 iSize value, however, I'll be sure to experiment with it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is because you are trying to update UI objects on a different thread. HAve you tried using the Dispatcher if using wpf? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx

or Invoke if using Winforms? https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: 
As @daylight pointed out to be, the UI was being updated in the progresschanged event, which executes on the thread which created the background worker, therefore there shouldn't be an issue regarding threading. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx for more info

Comment: I think the link that @demonplus posted will be helpful. Regardless of what the background worker is doing, it is a different thread to that which the UI objects are on, so you can't just update them as normal.

Comment: Actually, he seems to be updating the UI thread objects (label) properly by only doing that in the ProgressChanged event.  Using the ProgressChanged event to update UI elements is the correct way to do that and you can see that it works in my answer where I update a label on the form.  You just can't access UI (form) elements from the DoWork() method --- that's a separate thread of execution and will fail.

Comment: @daylight very true, I didn't think of this. For anyone who wants confirmation of this, the article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx states that "The ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread that created the BackgroundWorker." I'm new to StackOverflow, do you suggest I delete my answer or leave it?

Comment: I like that you examined what I said and kept the discussion open. I think you should just update it and mention that you discovered the new information. But I'm no SO expert so not sure.