# Change UpdateProgress text on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have this but it´s not working... did I miss something?

I need to change the text withing UpdateProgess on button click for example.

This is my `ascx`:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server"  AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upFormulario">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
            <%--<span id="lblInfo" style="border-width: 0px; position: fixed; padding: 50px; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 36px; left: 40%; top: 40%;">Loading...</span>--%>
            <asp:Label id="lblInfo" Text="..." runat="server" style="border-width: 0px; position: fixed; padding: 50px; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 36px; left: 40%; top: 40%;" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upFormulario" runat="server">
...
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">   
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Next" ID="btnSave" OnClick="cmdSaveDraft_Click" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" />
      </td> 
     </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This my code on `ascx.cs`

```
protected void cmdSaveDraft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label progressMessageLabel = this.UpdateProgress2.FindControl("lblInfo") as Label;
    if (progressMessageLabel != null)
    {
        progressMessageLabel.Text = "Saving...";
    }
    lblAccion = "Loading...";

    int iControl = this.ValidateCtrl();
    if (iControl == 1) 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Where is cmdSaveDraft_Click referenced in your view? I think your question needs more detail.

Comment: there is no error, I need to change the text within lblInfo label when a button is clicked. The cmdSaveDraft_Click is referenced in the updatepanel obviously.

Comment: You say "obviously" but I can't see the code...

Comment: I didn´t write ir because I think it wasn´t necesary

Comment: you can use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UpdateProgress is outside the UpdatePanel but your button is inside the update panel.

When you use an update panel, all the controls **inside** the update panel will work in ajax, they will not do real post but ajax request. In that case, only the controls inside the update panel can be updated from events fired from controls inside the update panel.

Resuming, if you want it to work add the update progress control inside the update panel and it will work.

Comment: oh yeah!! that was the problem!! Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

If the button being clicked has Post enabled then I would have thought the label would reflect the text changes on the next refresh of the page. (The button's click code gets executed on the server, not client. So it requires the page load to show the new state of the label)

If you want to have the label text change, without a refresh, you need to use Javascript.

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> document.getElementById("LABEL").text = 'Loading...'; </script>";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", script);
```

I have not tested this, but theoretically it should allow you to change the value of the label, without having to post the page.
Note - you might have to have the control's post disabled. Not sure.

Comment: it isn´t working. What I need is to change the text withing UpdateProgress to show it while an action is being done like : Loading, Saving, Deleting... when a selected button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759688/update-label-text-in-background-worker-winforms) can help:

```
public void bw_Convert_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{           
    e.Result = e.Argument;
    for (int i = 0; i <  fTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_CDR_ANALYZER (LNG_UPLOAD_ID, DAT_START, LNG_DURATION, INT_DIRECTION, INT_CALL_DATA_TYPE, \n" +
                "TXT_TARGET_NUMBER, TXT_OTHER_PARTY_NUMBER, TXT_TARGET_IMSI, TXT_TARGET_IMEI, TXT_TARGET_CELL_ID, TXT_ROAMING_NETWORK_COMPANY_NAME) VALUES \n" +
                "(@UPLOAD_ID, @START_DATE, @DURATION, @DIRECTION, @CALL_TYPE, @TARGET_NUMBER, @OTHER_PARTY_NUMBER, @IMSI, @IMEI, @CELL_ID, @ROAMING_NAME)", sqlCon);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UPLOAD_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@START_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["CallDate"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DURATION", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["CallDuration"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DIRECTION", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GetCallDirection(fTable.Rows[i]["CallDirection"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CALL_TYPE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GetCallType(fTable.Rows[i]["CallType"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TARGET_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["TargetNo"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OTHER_PARTY_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["OtherPartyNo"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMSI", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["IMSI"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["IMEI"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CELL_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["CellID"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ROAMING_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = fTable.Rows[i]["RoamingCompany"];
            sqlCon.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
        bw_Convert.ReportProgress((100 * i) / fTable.Rows.Count);  
      Label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        Label1.Text = i.ToString() + "Files Converted";});                 
    }    
}
```