# When reporting progress and updating ui listView control the whole program is stuck i can't click on other buttons why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I mean in backgroundworker i can click on other controls use other controls while the backgroundworker is working. But once i'm trying to update also the ui listView control it's updating but everything else is freezing/stuck i can't click and use any other controls until the backgroundworker finish the work.

```
int countUploadMsg = 0;
        private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MimeKit.HeaderList loaded = new MimeKit.HeaderList();
            List<string> test = new List<string>();
            int counter = 0;
            MimekitallLoadedMessages = new List<MimeKit.MimeMessage>();
            MimeKit.MimeMessage loadedMessage = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                string uid = seenUids[0];
                loadedMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(files[i].FullName);
                downloaded.Add(seenUids[i]);
                counter += 1;
                int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.Length;
                backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress, loadedMessage);
            }
         }
```

The progresschanged event

```
private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbt1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            pbt1.Invalidate();
            label9.Text = countUploadMsg.ToString();
            label9.Visible = true;
            MimeKit.MimeMessage Msg = e.UserState as MimeKit.MimeMessage;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(Msg.ToString());
      }
```

What did i try so far ? I added a Sleep for 1 ms and then changed it to 50ms in the dowork event after the ReportProgress line. W hen setting the Sleep to 50ms it was working fine but then it was very slow.

I also tried to update the MimekitallLoadedMessages List in the dowork event adding the loadedMessage to it and then reporting the MimekitallLoadedMessages List to the e.UserState or just updating the listView in the progressChanged event with the List.

Tried to add sleep of 1ms in the progressChanged.

The only so far is Sleep for 50ms in the dowork event but then the who process getting very slow.

I tried with also small amount of files i changed in the loop in the dowork the files.Length to 1000 even to 500 and same problem.

Even setting the Sleep to 50ms not all the times working smooth.

MimeKit is a email lib if it's matter at all:

[MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are doing more work in your `ProgressChanged` handler than you are in the background thread.  The worker thread is generating `ProgressChanged` events faster than the main thread can handle them.

You can use a [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to time the method block in the `DoWork` for-loop and also in the `ProgressChanged` handler.

You'll have to reconsider your approach here - a change of strategy will be needed.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a constraint of multithreaded object oriented programming.  You can only update UI elements from the thread responsible for them: the UI thread.  I think normally winforms throws an exception, you probably have those disabled somehow or caught by a try/catch wrapper.

This SO question answer is probably the direction you want to go in, but there may be much cleaner syntaxes for your situation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15759745

Also check out any of the results from this link to google search results:

https://www.google.com/#q=c%23+winforms+backgroundworker+update+ui

**Edit:** more info is usually better; J...'s answer is probably right on the OP's problem.  I didn't realize the BackgroundWorker's ProgressChanged EH is not handled by the BackgroundWorker's thread.  Maybe double check the DoWork is not throwing exceptions and (ducking gooses) BW is called from the UI thread.  State of the art on backgroundworkers:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is not the problem.  OP is doing UI updates in the `ProgressChanged` handler and this event is raised on the thread that created the `BackgroundWorker` (ie: the UI thread).